# Recoll: how to show n words before and after match?

Tags: recoll

I started to use recoll and wondered if there is the possibility to set an N number of words before and after the match to be shown in the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the recoll GUI, choose the menu option '**Preferences**'.

Then choose the option '**GUI configuration**'.

Click on the '**Search Parameters**' tab.

Look for '**Synthetic abstract context words**'.  Enter the **max number** of words to be displayed on both sides of the search term.  Default is 4.  I use 6.

Comment: Can this be done on the hidden preference files?